# Cannot resolve method "createStream" in "KafkaUtils"

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to stream data using Apache Kafka and Spark, but I get an error in line 24 of my code saying "Cannot resolve method "createStream" in "KafkaUtils"". I also tried using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream but that didn't work either. How do I resolve this error?
Below are my files that I am using

## NumbersConsumer.java

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class NumbersConsumer {

  public static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVER = "localhost:9092";
  public static final String GROUP_ID = "spark-group";
  public static final Map<String, Integer> TOPICS = new HashMap<>();

  public static final int BATCH_DURATION = 5000;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TOPICS.put("Demo1", 1);

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("demo");
    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(BATCH_DURATION));

    JavaPairDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext, BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, GROUP_ID, TOPICS);

    JavaPairDStream<String, String> percentage = messages.mapToPair(
        num -> new Tuple2<>("Percentage: ", num._2 + "%")
    );

    percentage.print();

    streamingContext.start();
    streamingContext.awaitTermination();
  }
}
```

## Pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testVideoKafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `provided` scope from streaming-kafka dependency.

You should add it to plain spark-steaming dependency instead.

Note from docs

> **Do not** manually add dependencies on org.apache.kafka artifacts (e.g. `kafka-clients`)

So remove that.

`createDirectStream` is correct - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

---

Also, Spark Streaming module for Kafka is largely considered deprecated, with Structured Streaming suggested instead (`spark-sql-kafka-0-10`)

Comment: I just removed <scope>provided</scope> from <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.13</artifactId> and added to <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.13</artifactId> and I still have that same error.

Comment: I just removed <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.13</artifactId> and added <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13</artifactId>, so now how do I resolve the new error "Cannot resolve symbol KafkaUtils"?

Comment: 1) If you're using Intellij, you need to edit Run configurations to include provided scope dependencies. 2)  KafkaUtils only exists in `spark-streaming-kafka`. Read the Structured Streaming documentation if you want to use it instead